# MongoDB, use a field as a value for subArray

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a structure like this

```
{_id : "id Assigned by Mongo" , 
 mainPost: "some text",
 comments: [],
 commentsCount : 0}
```

I am adding a new comment with

```
 update({_id: documentID}, {  $addToSet: { 'comments': {cText:text , ....}}});
```

but the comments document doesn't have an ID. is there anyway that mongo assign an ID to that subdocument?

I also can use the commentsCount as an ID for the subDocument before I increment it but I don't know how I can get it's value in MongoDB

```
update({_id: documentID}, {  $addToSet: {
        'comments': {commentID: ??? how to get commentsCount value??? , cText:text }}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make the database assign an id to sub-documents automatically, but you can do it manually in your application. The native MongoDB driver exposes the function `new ObjectId()` which generates an ObjectId with the same algorithm the database uses. All you need to do is assign it to a field of the sub-document you insert.

```
$addToSet: { 'comments': { _id: new ObjectId(), cText:text, ....}}
```

By the way: To update a document and simultaneously request it from the database, use [`collection.findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).

Comment: on Meteor it's Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() thanks a lot